# How to theme view header Global: Text Area?

Tags: 7, views, theming

I'm trying to stick a flexbox in a view's Header Global: Text area and there's a wrapping paragraph tag that I'm trying to theme away. The views-view.tpl.php only has 'print $header' inside the 'view-header' div so the errant 'p' must be rendered into the $header variable.

I can trim the paragraph tags from the $header variable in template.php with a post render hook, but I'd rather modify a tpl file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the `<p>` tag is inserted on the `Global: Text Area` header, but not on the `Global: Unfiltered text`. In case it is acceptable for you to use this one, it might fix your issue.

(by the way, in version 8 of Views, the `<p>` tag is not inserted any more for the `Global: Text Area` header)

Answer (score 0):

In settings.php add

```
$conf['theme_debug'] = TRUE;
```

View the source of the page and you will see the theme files being rendered and possible alternatives.

Comment: Neat trick, but it didn't help in this case. The comments just say that views-view.tpl.php is the template powering the header bit.

Comment: Yes I think that's it. The last time I did this I overwrote the page.tpl.php and custom loaded the lot. I was trying to combine a bunch of views and blocks though so overkill. You could try making the header text format 'php' and just printing the header that you want.